# Is there any reason for a beginner to use InnoDB when starting out with MySQL

Tags: java, python, mysql, database

I'm teaching myself SQL, and have chosen MySQL to learn on. I think I remember a couple classes using MySQL back in college and it seemed pretty straight forward.

That being said, the installation wants to know if I want to use InnoDB or a 'Standalone MySQL Server'. I do not understand the jargon describing the two options.

Standalone is the default, and probably for good reason. However, I wanted to know some of the pros for going with InnoDB, in terms that a beginner can understand. Again, I have read the description of the options and do not understand the jargon.

So the question is: What are some of the pros of choosing one option over the other in terms that a brand new learner can understand?

Comment: the inno db only in cluserst is missleading because a stand alone server also can have inndo see discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb

Answer (score 0):

Databases can be organized in a single server(your choice for the start) or clusters( if you go all the way, you want also try to use Multiple servers for replication or simply to share the workload.

The term Innodb is missleading.
Every database and Table can be InNodb.

there is a main discussion what the diffrences betweEn innoDb aND MMyISAM versus InnoDB

From the MySQL Website

> Standalone MySQL Server / Classic MySQL Replication (default)
>
> Select this option to configure one MySQL instance to run as a standalone database server. This option is ideal if you intend to set up classic replication later and then to include this server in your custom solution. The remaining configuration steps are described in the sections that follow, starting with Type and Networking.

And

> InnoDB cluster
>
> Select this option to create or extend an InnoDB cluster solution that is based on MySQL Group Replication (see Introducing InnoDB Cluster). You can configure (or reconfigure) a minimum of three server instances to perform a basic setup as a test-only sandbox cluster on a single computer or to create a production cluster inside a local network.

[More information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-workflow-innodb-cluster.html)

Comment: I read that already, hence my statement " I do not understand the jargon describing the two options." 

It would be nice if people read the question before assuming that I haven't read the documentation.

Comment: My first sentecte explains what it means, if you want more explanation, When there is something still not explained so ask.